# Can OmniGraffle for iOS open and edit PDFs?  

Tags: ipad, omnigraffle

OmniGraffle for OS X can open and edit PDFs.  Can OmniGraffle for iOS do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OmniGraffle product page for the iOS version](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle-ipad/features/) mentions that it can export PDFs. They don't seem to mention anywhere whether it will open PDFs, but that seems likely.